# Copy files from Azure Data Lake Store to Azure Storage with Azure Automation

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-automation

I want copy my files from Data Lake Store to Azure Storage per using Azure Automation.

I find a Get-AzureStorageFile cmdlet but it required as parameter "Directory" that have a CloudFileDirectory type.

Thanks :-)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Library functions for Azure Storage Account will not work on Azure Data Lake Storage

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to use the AzureRm.AzureDataLakeStore module.

Go to your Automation account and down to the "Modules" blade. Add module from the gallery.

[image]

Have a check in the runbook to make sure the module is loaded. Then perform upload or other Data Lake Store functions.

```html
# Check if the AzureRM.DataLakeStore module is loaded
If ((Get-Module -Name AzureRM.DataLakeStore -ListAvailable).Count -le 0) {
    Write-Log -Value "ERROR: The AzureRM.DataLakeStore module is not available, exiting script" -Color Red
    Write-Log -Value "Please Update Modules or download the Azure PowerShell modules from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/" -Color Yellow

    return
}

$myrootdir = "\"

Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "myadls.azuredatalakestore.net -Path "C:\sampledata\vehicle1_09142014.csv" -Destination $myrootdir\mynewdirectory\vehicle1_09142014.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AdlCopy to perform this. However, you need to configure a Hybrid Runbook Worker in your subscription and then install the AdlCopy. Then use the Azure Automation Runbook to run AdlCopy commands. (Select "Hybrid Worker" when you execute the runbook)

**Use AdlCopy (as standalone) to copy data from another Data Lake Storage Gen1 account:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob#use-adlcopy-as-standalone-to-copy-data-from-another-data-lake-storage-gen1-account

**Configure Hybrid Runbook Worker:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-windows-hrw-install#automated-deployment